# How can I add additional source files when customizing and rebuilding Debian package?

Tags: debian, packaging, customizing

I try to customize and rebuild a Debian source package by adding some additional source files (not included in the upstream archive) and applying some patches. More specifically, I try to customize Ubuntu "ppp" package by adding a custom plugin. I do the following:

1) I download and unpack source package with "apt-get source ppp"

2) I go into "ppp-x.x.x" subtree and rebuild the package cleanly with "dpkg-buildpackage -uc" to make sure that everything is ok with the source package. (And actually everything is ok for now).

3) Now I take my custom patches and place them into "debian/patches" subfolder of the "debian" subtree. Then I reference them in "debian/patches/series" file. I also take my custom source files, all in a single folder, say "tacacs", and place this folder into the "debian/extra" subfolder. I am not sure that I should place them exactly there but I don't see any more suitable place for them.

4) Now I try to run "dpkg-buildpackage -uc" again to build a custom package. And I see the following:

- "dpkg-buildpackage/dpkg-source/quilt" tries to apply my custom
  patches to my custom sources and cannot find them. So it fails and
  the build fails altogether.
- After the build fails and stops I can see my custom plugin ("tacacs") subfolder in the build tree but it is empty.
  So it is not surprise that patch failed.

So the question is: where should I place my custom source files and what else should I do to make "dpkg-source -b" see them and inject them to the build tree?

Comment: IIRC you need to enumerate them in `debian/files` or some such.

Comment: @tripleee Thank you, but I believe you are wrong about `debian/files` in the exact sense. As I see this file contains the list of the output files generated in the build. There are a lot of other files containing the lists in the `debian` directory and perhaps I will have to try them all I do not get a correct answer before.

Comment: Maybe I'm mixing it with `debian/install`.  Quick googling suggests that this is where you enumerate nonstandard files you want to have installed somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

I found two ways to solve my problem:

1. The first one seems to be more proper and idiomatic. It is to place
   additional sources to "the supplementary original tarball" named
   after the main original tarball with addition of the "component
   name" (as described in `man dpkg-source`). Supplementary tarballs
   are extracted over the main tarball before the build and additional
   code gets to the build tree where it can be patched and compiled.
   In fact my additional code was already packed to the archive, so I just had to rename the archive.

   Unfortunately this method did not work for me, since the code from supplementary tarballs
   can be injected to the root of the build tree only, and pppd plugin code
   should be placed to the `pppd/plugins` subdirectory. And I could not
   find a way to create a symlink to the code in the proper
   subdirectory with `dpkg-source/quilt`.
2. So I had to use the second method:

   - I unpacked additional source code directly to the proper place in the clean source tree created with `dpkg-source -x` (or `apt-get source`)
   - Then I applied `dpkg-source --commit` to the source directory and got a patch in the `debian/patches` subdirectory along with a proper `series` file referencing the newly-created patch. This patch contains all the changes that have occurred when additional sources were placed to the source tree. So the additional sources can be recreated in the proper place by reapplying this patch.
   - I saved the newly-created patch and the `series` file to the temporary location and deleted the source tree.
   - I recreated the clean source tree with `dpkg-source -x`.
   - I placed the saved patch and `series` file to the `debian/patches` folder of the source tree again. I also edited `debian\changelog` and `debian\control` to indicate that the new version of the package should be build and not mess the new package with the original one.
   - Now I could build a new version of the package with `dpkg-buildpackage -uc -us`. This was not a final version yet, since it did not contain my custom patches, but it did already contain my custom sources.
   - At last I added my custom patches to the `debian/patches` directory, added references to them to the `debian/patches/series` file, ran `dpkg-buildpackage` once more and got the package I wanted to get.

Though this method works with the source code injections to any desired place in the source tree, it has a drawback that additional sources should be unpacked manually, mixed with the original code and converted to the patch. All this manipulations have to be repeated each time this additional code is renewed. Whereas in the first method it is enough to replace the supplementary tarball with its new version and to make sure that all the subsequent patches apply well.